# getting average of inserts per day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table

```
CREATE TABLE public.listing
(
  id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('listing_id_seq'::regclass),
  listing_url text NOT NULL,
  insert_time timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT listing_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT listing_listing_url UNIQUE (listing_url)
)
```

How can I get the average number of rows that were inserted per day for the past week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just take the number of records appearing in the past week, and divide by 7 for the number of days in a week:

```
select count(*) / 7
from public.listing
where insert_time > current_date - interval '7 days'   -- inserts happening in past week
```

Answer (score 0):

select COUNT(*)/7 from Listing where insert_time between '2016-09-01' and '2016-09-07' group by insert_time